# Problem with ParallelTable?

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to numerically solve Bloch equations using Euler's method. My code is the following

```
γ = 1.;  
b = {0., 0., 1.};  
θ = π/6.;  
ϕ = 0.;  
ic = {Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ], Cos[θ]};  
m0 := ic;  
m[Δt_] := m0 + Δt γ Cross[m0, b];  
run[Δt_, n_] := Table[α = m[Δt]; ic = α, {t, 1, n}];  
run1 = run[0.01, 1000];  
ListPlot[Table[Flatten[Take[run1, All, {j}]], {j, 3}], Joined -> True,  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

This gives the correct result. However if I use ParallelTable instead of Table

```
run[Δt_, n_] := ParallelTable[α = m[Δt]; ic = α, {t, 1, n}];
```

I get the following
[image]

What is the cause of this? ParallelTable also takes longer than Table as well. Sorry I can't get the formatting of the greek letters correctly...

Comment: Please copy and paste your code again from *Mathematica* and do not attempt to format the Greek letters.  (They will appear as e.g. `\[Phi]`.)

Comment: thank you. I re-copied the mathematica code.

Comment: For such a short calculation, the overhead of parallel computations dominates any savings from using multiple processors.

Comment: Hi bbgodfrey. This is the equation of motion for only one particle. Eventually I'd like to extend this to many interacting particles, which I was hoping paralleltable would be helpful.

Comment: The problem, I believe, is that each of the parallel processes is independently changing `ic`.  Better, I believe to calculate trajectories of multiple particles in parallel than to try to compute the trajectory of one particle with multiple processors.

Comment: Thank you. But if that is the case then this problem will also arise in many particle simulation as well.

Comment: That depends on how the particles interact.  In PIC plasma codes, all particle are advanced one time step in parallel, fields are recalculated and applied to particles, and the particles are again advanced one time step in parallel.

Comment: I see your point. We can compute the fields within one timestep in parallel then advance to the next timestep. So can we say that mathematica cannot parallelize over many timesteps because it cannot update initial conditions correctly? This is not a serious issue since the most time consuming part is the field calculations, not the timestep. But I am curious to know if there is a solution.

Comment: I believe that it is not possible, even in principle, to solve the time history of a single particle using parallel processes, because processors needing initial conditions from earlier segments of the trajectory need to wait until those segments are computed.